# Pandas: pivoting rows to columns with columns as column-row

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transpose, melt

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [11,12,13]})
df

    A   B
0   1   11
1   2   12
2   3   13
```

I would like to create the following data frame where the columns are a combination of each column-row

```
    A0  A1  A2  B0  B1  B2
0   1   2   3   11  12  13
```

It seems that the pivot and transpose functions will switch columns and rows but I actually want to flatten the data frame to a single row. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
s=df.stack().sort_index(level=1).to_frame(0).T
s.columns=s.columns.map('{0[1]}{0[0]}'.format) 
s
   A0  A1  A2  B0  B1  B2
0   1   2   3  11  12  13
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, with [pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_wider):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd

df.index = [0] * len(df)
df = df.assign(num=range(len(df)))
df.pivot_wider(names_from="num", names_sep = "")

   A0  A1  A2  B0  B1  B2
0   1   2   3  11  12  13
```